# I am unable to disable future date in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery

Here is my code.For any help thanks in advance.

```
<input type="text" id="hoDate" name="date" class="startDatePicker" required/>
```

And my jquery code is:

```
    $(function() {
      $( "#hoDate" ).datepicker({  maxDate: newDate() });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add space between new Date(). Try this:

```
$( "#hoDate" ).datepicker({  maxDate: new Date() });
```

To automatically set end date as start date selected:

```
<input type="text" id="hoDate" name="date" class="startDatePicker" required/>
<input type="text" id="endDate" name="enddate" class="endDatePicker" required/>

$( "#hoDate" ).datepicker({  
    maxDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $("#endDate").val(selected)
    }
});
```

Comment: Try this:  $("#datepicker").datepicker({maxDate: '+0d'});

Comment: but  end datepicker not picking the value

Comment: means do you have 2 datepicker?

Comment: ok datepicker is coming in end date?? and which validations do you need in end date?

Comment: date is not coming in end date textbox,i want validation i.e when i select the start date then automatically  end date should be also same as start date,because i put it display-none style